# Is there a way to make plots appear as an integrated window in Spyder (like RStudio does)?

Tags: matplotlib, spyder

Is there a way to make plots appear in an integrated window on spyder (like in the help space) instead of inline (not practical and no way to zoom) and not as a pop-up window (in my case it always appears on a different space as I use spyder in full screen mode)?

I tried the OSX/Qt4/QT5 settings and they still appear on a separate window.

I would want the same setting as in RStudio where I can go back and forth between plots and not have to deal with windows 'floating' around. Is there a way to work it that way or it does not exist yet?

Comment: No, such option does not exist in spyder.

Comment: ok thank you, it would be nice though ! Found that someone made it a suggestion on GitHub. Hopefully becomes a reality soon ! https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2550

Answer (score 3):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) A dedicated pane that shows all plots generated in our consoles is already implemented and will be part of our next major version (Spyder 4, to be released in 2019). [Here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/pull/6430) you can find some screenshots of that pane.